# How to make JQuery UI TimePicker format time in 24 H format?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datetimepicker

I want to format time in 24 h format. In the documentation it says that time format is specified by `timeFormat, altTimeFormat, and pickerTimeFormat`. I put the following lines into `this._defaults`

```
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
        altTimeFormat: "HH:mm",
        pickerTimeFormat: "HH:mm"
```

But still, the time is formatted in 12 H AM/PM format, such as here:

[image]

In fact, time inside the component is shown correctly, but time in the text field is not output correctly.

I debugged the script with Firebug and found that the problem lies in the argument of the following method call:

```
$.datepicker.formatTime = function(format, time, options) {
```

Here, the argument `format` has the value `h:mmtt`.

This method is called by `_onTimeChange` function:

```
this.formattedTime = $.datepicker.formatTime(o.timeFormat, this, o);
```

Here, the variable `o` is set to:

```
o = this._defaults,
```

I have already defined `timeFormat` inside the initilization of `this._defaults`. But somehow this is changed then. I couldn't find out when it is changed?

Can someone show me the right way to format time in 24 H format?

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me.. http://jsfiddle.net/6TMuZ/

Comment: I found out what caused the unexpected behaviour: The framework that I use was overriding the default settings as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105938/how-to-change-date-and-time-format-in-pods-frameworks-date-and-timepicker-compo