# How to change date and time format in Pods Framework's Date and TimePicker Components?

Tags: wordpress, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, podscms

I was [fighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105598/how-to-make-jquery-ui-timepicker-format-time-in-24-h-format) with timepicker's default settings. The default settings were overridden somehow. Then, I noticed that they were actually overridden by Pods Framework's code:

```
var pods_form_ui_pods_field_baslangic_tarihi_args = {"timeFormat":"h:mmtt","dateFormat":"mm\/dd\/yy","ampm":true};
```

I would like to change the default settings of date and time formatting. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer.

You need to got to the `Edit Pod` page and enter the date/time field and go to "Additional Field Options":

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the date format field

- `m`  shows month as 2 digits ie `06`,
- `n`  shows month as 1 digit ie `6`,
- `l` shows day of week in full ie `Monday`,
- `o` shows full year ie `2018`,
- `a` shows `am` or `pm`,
- `A` shows `AM` or `PM`,
- `F` shows full month name ie `June`
- `S` shows date number suffix such as `rd` or `th` in `23rd` or `4th`